# Couldn't Stanford have typed 'Bill Cipher?'

Tags: gravity-falls

In the last episode, Weirdmageddon 3, Stanford Pines types 'Stanley Pines' into the memory gun to erasing Bill Cipher. But, if erasing Stan's memory would destroy Bill Cipher, why couldn't Stanford have typed 'Bill Cipher' instead of 'Stanley Pines?'

Comment: I doubt that this has an answer besides "that's how the gun works" - presumably, since Bill is not an actual part of Stan's mind, the gun cannot target him specifically. This forces them to use the scorched-earth approach; they take out the whole area he's hiding in, knowing he'll die in the metaphorical flames.

Comment: @DavidS Write this as an answer and I'm sure it'll be acceptable.